# How to enable javascript in client window if it disables it in his browser?

Tags: javascript, html

How to enable javascript in client window if it disables it in his browser?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use the `<noscript>` tag to display a message and ask the user to enable javascript.

Comment: but if we want that the client side javascript automatically enable for that website session period

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to enable javascript in client window if it disables it in his
>   browser?

If Web browser features could be bypassed, users would feel very insecure surfing the Web. Short answer: not ever possible (for security reasons).

Maybe your Web app requires JavaScript. You can ask the user to enable JavaScript to be able to experience your Web site/app including a `<noscript>Hey, enable it please!</noscript>` tag.

> but if we want that the client side javascript automatically enable
>   for that website session period

For now, this isn't possible.

Comment: i know this if you have another answer please tell me

Comment: @sandeep_1994 There's no other answer, sadly